# android eclipse basegameutils mGoogleApiClient.connect() crash

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x, google-api-client

I'm making a game using Cocos2d-x in Eclipse and I want to implement Leaderboards, I've downloaded basegameutils and UtilActivity from:

https://github.com/cpinan/Cocos2dX_GooglePlayGamesServices
and added to my project.

I changed in my java file:

public class MYCLASS extends UtilActivity

and now then I run my project it's crashing. I fount that when I comment this line of code in GameHelper.java in this method "public void onStart(Activity act)"

mGoogleApiClient.connect();

then app runs.

Can someone help? Or give example code.

Comment: Got a simular problem myself. Did you ever find out what is was`?